# TypeScript: `Any' in destructuring of object from function call

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a strange behavior when I do destructuring from function call - the variables that I get becomes `any`. But if I don't do destructuring they have correct types. One thing is that it depends on arguments quantity. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20contexts%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7Bc%3A%201%7D%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AppContexts%20%3D%20typeof%20contexts%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20useApp%3C%0D%0A%20%20C%20extends%20Array%3Ckeyof%20AppContexts%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20ResultContexts%20extends%20Pick%3CAppContexts%2C%20C%20extends%20(infer%20K)%5B%5D%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%3E%0D%0A%3E(...list%3A%20C)%3A%20ResultContexts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20one%20%3D%20useApp('a'%2C%20'b')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aone.a.c%20%2F%2F%20good%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20b%20%7D%20%3D%20one%3B%20%2F%2F%20good%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20%7B%20a%20%7D%20%3D%20useApp('a')%3B%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20a%20%2F%2F%20a%20is%20any%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20%7B%20a%20%7D%20%3D%20useApp('a'%2C%20'b')%3B%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20a%20%2F%2F%20a%20is%20number)

```
const contexts = { a: {c: 1}, b: 2 }

type AppContexts = typeof contexts;

export function useApp<
  C extends Array<keyof AppContexts>,
  ResultContexts extends Pick<AppContexts, C extends (infer K)[] ? K : never>
>(...list: C): ResultContexts {
    return null as any;
}

const one = useApp('a', 'b');

one.a.c // good
const { b } = one; // good


// const { a } = useApp('a'); 
// a // a is any

// const { a } = useApp('a', 'b'); 
// a // a is number
```

Comment: Does this suit your needs? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20contexts%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7Bc%3A%201%7D%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AppContexts%20%3D%20typeof%20contexts%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20useApp%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20AppContexts%3E(%0D%0A%20%20...list%3A%20T%5B%5D%0D%0A)%3A%20Pick%3CAppContexts%2C%20T%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: `a is number` --- is it?

Comment: @Caramiriel Yes, your solution works, but anyway, my example looks like TypesScript's bug

Comment: @zerkms here `// const { a } = useApp('a'); // a // a is any` it is `any`, but it looks like a bug

Comment: @aspirisen indeed, but in the latest line `a` is not inferred as a `number`.

Comment: @zerkms yeah, it is an object with a number, but anyway it is infered

Comment: @aspirisen I agree with you it looks like a bug though. If you file an issue could you please leave a comment here with a link to it